# is there any LINQ expression to convert a Datatable to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a number of cases where i do a query and get a datatable and convert it to either a:

```
 Dictionary<string, string>
```

or

```
 Dictionary<int, int>
```

or

```
 Dictionary<string, [Someobject]>
```

i could create my own function with a  loop but i wanted to see if there was any LINQ way of converting a datatable into a dictionary and just passing 2 lambdas for the key and value (similar like you can do with converting IEnumerable to dictionary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) & [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb548657.aspx):

For example, if you want a dictionary where keys are from col1 and values from col2:

```
table.AsEnumerable()
     .ToDictionary<int, string>(row => row.Field<int>(col1),
                                row => row.Field<string>(col2));
```

Comment: It would be nicer to use the [`Field()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method rather than indexing then casting.

Comment: @manji - this doesn't compile for me . .  it can't resolv the Field property . .i am using .net 3.5 if that helps

Comment: Have added a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`?

Comment: @manji - i didn't before, but adding it didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Even with `using System.Data` instruction? It's included in 3.5, it should work.

Comment: This code does not work. Specifying a selector for the key and another one for the elment only works with the non-generic version of ToDictionary().

Answer (score 4):

Linq comes with a [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) extension method that sounds like what you're describing.

Edit

As far as using ToDictionary with a DataTable: I don't see why not.

```
DataTable dt = GetMyDataTable();
return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(r => r["KeyColumn"], r => r["ValueColumn"]);
```

You need the cast in there because DataTable.Rows is just `IEnumerable`, rather than `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Comment: I know that (as mentioned in the question).  i wanted to see if there was an equavalent from a data table ??

Comment: you can also use `dt.AsEnumerable()` to obtain an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Comment: @Anthony Yeah, that's why I upvoted @manji's answer. :) Been too long since I had to work with DataSets!